# Deleting a FHIR resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm coming to opinion that the Blaze server has not fully supported deleting of a FHIR resource. Could someone help with the following questions:

1. When a resource is deleted, is a new version of the resource created and does this modify that last updated date/time?
2. When a resource history is requested, is an atom deleted-entry present for the specific version.
3. How are resources undeleted and does this create a resource version.

BTW: Blaze is doing logical deletes not physical deletes. It would nice for testing if there was someway to specify that a physical delete should be performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1 - yes

you create a new version that marks it as deleted. The last updated date/time does change, though I'm not sure where that would manifest?

## 2 - yes

you would have the atom deleted entry for that version that marks it as deleted

## 3 - maybe

you can't "undelete" a resource, but you can post a new version over the top of a deleted version, which creates a new resource version that's not marked as deleted. This can go on indefinitely...

No one has asked for physical deletes before. I don't think my system can honour such a request, and I don't think that any healthcare system should. Testing... maybe... but sounds like an extension to the spec to me